# помогите разобраться с @login_required(redirect_field_name=' ')

Tags: django, python-3.6, users

пытаюсь реализовать доступ к добавлению товара в корзину только пользователей прошедших авторизацию.

декоратор login_required и его использование в принципе понятно. не ясно только как используя redirect_field_name перенаправить пользователя (после заполнения формы авторизации) на страницу товара который он пытался добавить в корзину перед авторизацией.

вот пример views.py

```
@login_required(redirect_field_name='')
@require_POST
def cart_add(request, product_id):
    cart = Cart(request)
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=product_id)
    form = CartAddProductForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        cd = form.cleaned_data
        cart.add(product=product,
                 quantity=cd['quantity'],
                 update_quantity=cd['update'])
    return redirect('cart:cart_detail')
```

updated views.py

```
@login_required
def cart_add(request, product_id):
    cart = Cart(request)
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=product_id)
    form = CartAddProductForm(request.POST)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            cart.add(product=product,
                     quantity=cd['quantity'],
                     update_quantity=cd['update'])
        return redirect('cart:cart_detail')
    else:
        return redirect('shop:product_detail')
```

Comment: redirect_field_name тут не поможет. Поведение, которое вы ожидаете, заложено в Джанго по умолчанию. Единственное, на мой взгляд, что может препятствовать этому поведению у вас - это require_POST. Попробуйте вместо него переопределить проверку POST/GET через if/else, и на get сделать редирект на страницу товара

Comment: пример того что вышло прикрепил к вопросу, скорее всего не правильно вас понял. немогли бы указать на мою ошибку? так как данныцй код не работает.

Comment: я имел в виду поместить внутрь первого условия весь ваш код, а на else сделать HttpResponseRedirect на страницу товара. Я правда не знаю, куда вас должен привести shop:product_detail. Вам нужно получить правильную страницу товара (например, из истории)

Comment: Вообще в идеале, чтобы вью отправки в корзину и товара совпадало. Для отправки в корзину - post, для просмотра товара - get. Тогда не будет всех этих танцев с редиректами